# Other units of resistance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, units, electrical-resistance

Resistance is $\frac{V}{I}$, and we get the unit $\Omega$.

Another unit is $\frac{W}{A^2}$. How do you derive that unit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watts are a unit of power, $P=IV$. considering the units:
$$ \frac{[W]}{[A]^2} = \frac{[A][V]}{[A]^2} = \frac{[V]}{[A]} $$
therefore the units are the same.

In general you can determine the  units of anything by considering the equations to determine it and substituting all the variables for their units.